# how do I auto generate interface from Aqua table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, annotations

Is there an online auto generator for generating a java interface which it's data members are taken from an *Aqua table* (or *mysql*)

for *example*:

Aqua table: `CLIENT_TABLE`

`**COLUMN_NAME** = CLIENT ID`,  `**DATA_TYPE**= SY_CLIENT`

I want to generate this code :

```
@VO
@Table(name = "CLIENT_TABLE")
public interface InsertToClientTabletQuery extends ValueObject {
    @Property
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", type =  SybaseTypes.SY_CLIENT)
    String getClientId();

    void setClientId(String client);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: libraries, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: Follow this tutorial and do it yourself. http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101